# Reviews verdict to a First Question that is being commented by users as too naive

Tags: discussion, review-queues

If I'm reviewing a question that is being commented by users as too naive because it has serveal logical errors in the code statements. What should be the verdict of the review?

I'm referring to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319411/error-map-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

Comment: Is the question answerable?  Is it not just a typographical error?  Could it potentially help others with a similar issue (once the issue is isolated and exposed)?  Review the question on these merits and see what you come up with.  It's no standard way, but I feel that it's appropriate.

Comment: It is not too naive. It has too many problems. OP has essentially dumped what appears to be the result of some random cut and paste into a question, then expects someone to fix all the problems.

Answer (score 4):

The linked question contains:

- An actual error message
- Code to reproduce this error message
- The error seems to be caused by something else than a typo.

The question doesn't seem to be exceptionally good, but the question is still clear and answerable. The comments seem to point out the quality of the written code, but votes on questions should not be based on that. As long as the code allows someone to reproduce the problem, and the size of the code is reasonable, we shouldn't worry about the code. I would give an upvote if the score is < 1 (a little bit of reputation showing they are doing the right thing), or otherwise click "No action needed". In general, if the question isn't exceptionally good, I don't want to raise the score too much.

Comment: "I would give an upvote if the score is < 1" - please don't. Voting should be independent on the existing votes. It is _extremely_ annoying to downvote a post just to have it jump back to zero in a split second.

Comment: This is pretty much the only case I upvote based on a score. I never 'correct' a score by downvoting. A first question that isn't necessarily bad should have some positive score, but I don't want to upvote a question that isn't exceptionally good for the sole reason it is the first question asked by an user.

Comment: "A first question that isn't necessarily bad should have some positive score" - I am not entirely sure about that. If a question isn't bad, but it isn't particularly useful or interesting either, there is no harm in keeping it at zero.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I beleive that question doesn't show that the user made any research about the topic he is asking. I mean if you put a statement like `cout << "Hello"` outside the main method you don't know the basics of c++ and you should try to learn about it first before facing a bigger problem like trying to code a simple game. Personally I don't like questions that consists on chunks of code with simple grammatical errors. I just clicked **No action needed**.